# Angular application on Tomcat 404 on reload or deeplinking

Tags: angular, tomcat

I have a Tomcat server that hosts many Angular 14 applications. Each application is on a folder on the webapps directory (eg "webapps/example", "webapps/test"...).

When I build the Angular applications I set the base-href to be "./":

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href ./
```

So the applications work. When I go to http://server.com/example or http://server.com/test everything works. But when I refresh a page or input directly a deep link (eg http://server.com/example/user/1) I get a 404.

I have added this to Tomcat:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
```

And every application has a WEB-INF folder with an web.xml file (eg webapps/example/WEB-INF/web.xml and webapps/test/WEB-INF/web.xml) with this content:

```
<web-app>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

But I still get 404 when I refresh or input a deep link.

Any thougts or help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was on the Angular side. When I set the base href to "./" I tell the application "run from this route", so the deep urls didn't work because it wanted to grab the js and css from that route.

I changed the base href to the folders name, as an absolute route, and it started working.

Comment: HI, I'm having the same problem. Deep links and refreshing aren't working in localhost or on my published server. However, i am not publishing to a folder but to the root of a domain. Do you have any suggestions you could share for why this is?

Comment: Hi Emma, have you tried the web.xml part I mentioned? With that file you tell the web server that everything "not found" should be redirected to the Angular app, so that it handles by itself.